# Error using unique pointer from interface as attribute of a class

Tags: arm, unique-ptr

In a nutshell, I need help with the right use of `unique_ptr` and not with the library `ArmNN`. So, the next paragraph is just for contextualization.

I am adapting my current application to use the library [ArmNN](https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn). More specifically, I am doing that through the use of the interface [ICaffeParser](https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn/blob/branches/armnn_19_11/include/armnnCaffeParser/ICaffeParser.hpp).

At line 22 of this interface, we have this `using` definition to define a `unique_ptr` to the interface, that I believe is the "cause" of my problems.

```
using ICaffeParserPtr = std::unique_ptr<ICaffeParser, void(*)(ICaffeParser* parser)>;
```

I am quite sure my problem is the incorrect use of `unique_ptr` in my context, once I could make some successful tests with a more simple application.

My current code contains a class, let's call it `MyClass`:

```
namespace MYNAMESPACE {
    class MyClass {
        public:
            MyClass() {
            }
            // a lot of functions
            // a lot of attributes
        private:
            // a lot of functions
            // a lot of attributes
    }
}
```

In order to make use of the `ArmNN` library, I have created a new `private` attribute for `MyClass`:

```
armnnCaffeParser::ICaffeParserPtr myParser;
```

and instantiated `myParser` at `MyClass()` constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
    myParser = armnnCaffeParser::ICaffeParser::Create();
}
```

Remembering `ICaffeParserPtr` is a `unique_ptr` (I think), now I have the following compiling error:

```
/my_path/src/detector.cpp: In constructor ‘MYNAMESPACE::MyClass::MyClass()’:
/my_path/src/detector.cpp:13:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<armnnCaffeParser::ICaffeParser, void (*)(armnnCaffeParser::ICaffeParser*)>::unique_ptr()’
MyClass::MyClass() {
                 ^
In file included from /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
             from /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/locale:43,
             from /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
             from /usr/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h:40,
             from /usr/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_index.h:49,
             from /usr/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h:42,
             from /usr/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:43,
             from /usr/include/opencv2/flann.hpp:48,
             from /usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:62,
             from /my_path/src/detector.hpp:11,
             from /my_path/src/detector.cpp:1:
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:255:2: note: candidate: template<class _Up, class> std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Up>&&)
unique_ptr(auto_ptr<_Up>&& __u) noexcept;

/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:255:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/my_path/src/detector.cpp:13:20: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
 MyClass::MyClass() {
                  ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because `myParser` is actually being default-initialized and *then* assigned on the constructor body of `MyClass::MyClass()`.

Since a function pointer is passed as a custom deleter to `std::unique_ptr` to form the `ICaffeParserPtr` type, the default constructor for this particular instance of `std::unique_ptr` is disabled as per [[unique.ptr.single.ctor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.ctor).

In other words, `ICaffeParserPtr`, for safety reasons, cannot be default-initialized — which specific function to otherwise assign as its deleter on initialization?

To address this, you should always initialize class members at the member initializer list. In this case, initialize `myParser` as such:

```
MyClass::MyClass():
  myParser(armnnCaffeParser::ICaffeParser::Create()) {}
```

This avoids calling the unavailable default constructor for `std::unique_ptr`, and is generally a better practice than assigning to class members in the constructor body.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did like you suggested and now it is compiling correctly. I've been searching for two days.